# Actuarial claims reserving with the chain-ladder method

Tags: c#

Hello there and beforehand a huge thank you to everybody for dedicating their time to help others.

This is my first post here, so I hope I comply to the guidelines. Maybe a bit background to myself: I do not have a formal education in computer science except for some basic introductory level courses at university. I have worked as a trainee in software development for a year until the whole team was dismissed due to management decisions. During that time, I mainly did some programming for the company's ERP system. As ERP development differs from "conventional" programming a lot, the few things I (think I) know are self taught, so they're pretty error-prone. Now I'm working at an insurance company in a non-IT-role, but thought of doing some programming finger exercises related to my new job resulting in a small class library for actuarial claims reserving with the chain-ladder method, others might be added as well. The whole repository can be found at [my github](https://github.com/jb262/ActuarialMaths.NonLife).

Well, to my questions:

**Namespaces**: Currently I have split the source files by topic, e.g. Exceptions, Reserving methods and the underlying model.

```cs
namespace ActuarialMaths.NonLife.ClaimsReserving.Model
namespace ActuarialMaths.NonLife.ClaimsReserving.Methods
namespace ActuarialMaths.NonLife.ClaimsReserving.Exceptions
```

While the split does make sense inside the project, to me the namespaces seem too granular for a library that would be used by another project. On the other hand, throwing the exceptions, the model and the methods into one single namespace, it might become too cluttered at some point. What would be the better solution in this situation?

**Data structures**: I took some inspiration from the .NET stack implementation and modelled the run-off triangles, respectively the underlying paid claims with a jagged two-dimensional array, which has an initial capacity which is doubled when needed.

```cs
public abstract class Triangle
{
    private const int initialCapacity = 8;
    protected decimal[][] claims;
    private int capacity;

    protected Triangle(int periods)
    {
        capacity = initialCapacity;
        while (capacity < periods)
        {
            capacity *= 2;
        }
        claims = new decimal[capacity][];

        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            claims[i] = new decimal[capacity - i];
        }

        Periods = periods;
    }

    public virtual void AddClaims(IEnumerable<decimal> values)
    {
        Periods++;

        if (capacity < values.Count())
        {
            capacity *= 2;

            Array.Resize(ref claims, capacity);

            for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref claims[i], capacity - i);
            }
        }
    }
```

The idea was that first, the array is only there to store the values. No fancy overhead of e.g. a List is needed. The values just need to be set and retrieved by some indices, be it by row, column, both or diagonal.
On the other hand, modelling a triangle as a list of other lists which represent the diagonals would make basic operations on the triangle a lot easier such as simply setting/returning/adding a collection at a given index instead of fiddling around with for-/foreach-loops and incrementing/decrementing indices.
Is the current implementation a valid idea or does readability beat leaving out unneccessary overhead here?

**Interfaces**: In the job mentioned above, I somehow developed the (bad?) habit of creating an interface for everything, so the initial version of my code had an additional interface on top:

```cs
public interface ITriangle : ISliceable<decimal>, ICloneable
{
    int Periods { get; }
    void AddClaims(IEnumerable<decimal> values);
}
```

The abstract class Triangle then implemented the interface ITriangle. Halfway through I realized that there is basically no other way of implementing a base run-off triangle in this specific domain and deleted the interface,
thus removing a layer of abstraction. While there is no inherent need for the reserving method to know how the triangle is implemented as long as it provides the neccessary methods and properties, is there really a need to **always** program against an interface when dealing with objects containing some logic, although there is no (at least obvious) possibility that it could be implemented in another way than already done?
The same goes for the "run-off square" where not even an abstract class would be needed.

**Naming of methods**: While e.g. `GetColumn(int column)` and `SetColumn(IEnumerable<decimal> values, int column)` in the ISliceable interface need their leading adjectives to be able to tell anyone what they are doing, I left them out when naming the methods to retrieve calculated values when dealing with reserving methods, e.g. the method to retrieve the total reserve is called `TotalReserve()` instead of `GetTotalReserve()`. I thought that adding "Get"s in front of everything would clutter the code, but now, it somewhat seems to me that this somehow obfuscates what the methods are actually doing.
Are there supposed to be "clearer" names althought it's impossible to manually set these values and it should be clear that these methods are meant to retrieve the values?

**Placement of methods**: While the `CalculateReserves()` and `CalculateCashflows()` methods actually make sense on the square since they only need the values stored inside a square, they make no sense at all when the claims/losses strored in the sqaure have not been developed from a triangle by a reserviong method. Again on the other hand, putting that inside a reserving method, even inside an abstract base class, would lead to code duplications when I added simulation based methods.
Is it better to place the method on the object "it's working on" or on the class that provides the logic that makes the meaningful execution of the method possible?

**Memoization**: Inside the reserving methods, basically everything is memoized, e.g.:

```cs
public Square Projection()
{
    if (projection == null)
    {
        projection = CalculateProjection();
    }

    return projection;
}
```

While this makes sense for more complicated stuff like the projection above, it seems a bit off to me for some calculations, e.g.

```cs
public IEnumerable<decimal> CalculateCashflows()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Periods - 1; i++)
    {
        int diagonal = Periods + i;

        yield return GetDiagonal(diagonal)
            .Take(Periods - 1 - i)
            .Zip(GetDiagonal(diagonal - 1), (x, y) => x - y).Sum();
    }
}
```

I'd say it would make sense if the column was long, but given the domain, it's rarely longer than 20 elements, making recalculating it every time it's needed not too expensive. So, is it sensible to store the calculated values inside a private class array instead of recalculating it?

Thanks in advance! If anyone wants to look at the entire code code and notices something off there as well, I'd really appreciate constructive criticism.

Comment: Welcome to code review where we review working code and provide suggestions on how the code can be reviewed. While we really do appreciate information about the project to help with the review, anything you want reviewed must be posted in the question. Within the post, anything in code that implies that some of the code is hidden such as `...` will make the question off-topic because that implies that it is hypothetical code rather than real code. If the project is large you can post it in separate questions as long as the code in any one question supports itself.

Comment: Code review guidelines can be found at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: On top of the links provided by pacmaninbw, we have a very shiny [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915), which may help improve your (future) questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the namespace Models is fine, but methods and exceptions should not be in the namespaces. 
Exceptions, should be handled for each class. So, if you moved all exceptions under one namespace `Exceptions`, this means `Exceptions` namespace will be referenced in all classes (entire project). So, it'll be better to avoid doing that. For the methods namespace, not sure what do you intent to use it for, but surely, rename it to something more specific will be better, for instance, if you meant `Methods` as extensions or helper methods, you could rename it to `Util` or `Utility` or anything meaningful.
For the beginning on the project, don't think too much about it as you'll have a better idea on what namespace should be there.

For the abstract class, i don't have a full understand on the actual usage of it other than the provided logic, but converting it to `List<IEnumerable<decimal>>` seems the right one for you. It will give you more advantages than the current 2D array. Firstly, it'll eliminate the need of the maintaining the capacity. Secondly, it will short things up and let's you focus on your actual logic on managing the data. So, if you convert it to list, and add the basic functionality to your abstract it should give you something like this :

```
public abstract class Triangle : IEnumerable<IEnumerable<decimal>>
{
    private readonly List<IEnumerable<decimal>> claims = new List<IEnumerable<decimal>>();

    protected Triangle()
    {
        // since you're using List<IEnumerable<decimal>>, there is no need to maintain the capacity, unless if you need a fixed capacity
    }

    public IEnumerable<decimal> this[int index]
    {
        get => claims[index];
        set => claims[index] = value;
    }

    public int Count => claims.Count;


    public void Add(IEnumerable<decimal> values)
    {
        claims.Add(values);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        claims.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(IEnumerable<decimal> values)
    {
        return claims.Contains(values);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, IEnumerable<decimal> values)
    {
        claims.Insert(index, values);
    }

    public void Remove(int index)
    {
        claims.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public int RemoveAll(Predicate<IEnumerable<decimal>> match)
    {
        return claims.RemoveAll(match);
    }

    public IEnumerator<IEnumerable<decimal>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return claims.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return claims.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I've chosen to implement `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<decimal>>` interface, to empower the class with the use of `foreach` loop and `Linq` extensions.

However, you shouldn't remove your interface as implementing an interface is never a bad habit, actually, it's recommend to use interfaces on all classes that might be reused with other classes (concrete or abstract). For instance, if other developers wants to implement a class that would inherit `Triangle`, they either its interface, abstract, or concrete class. Sometime, the class needs to inherit multiple classes, and there is no straight forward way to inherit them all unless we use their interfaces. So, always keep an interface for your classes, and implement it on your classes as well. You should also keep the interface with the minimum required functionality. You can implement other interfaces in your class or implement them on your interface and then implement your interface on your class. Both options are valid options.

For the naming convention, sometimes, you'll need to wrap functions under new naming convention to make it understandable and clearer for other developers as well. So, there is nothing wrong using `Get` or `Set` prefixes as naming convention, and it makes things more readable for most of the time, but sometimes the implementation would forces you to use a different naming convention based on the business logic requirement, in this case, you might want to keep the required naming public, and it it  could have a callback to private setter and getter methods .. for instance, you can do something like this :

```
public abstract class Triangle
{
    public IEnumerable<decimal> this[int index] 
    {
        get => GetColumn(index);
        set => SetColumn(value, index);
    }

    public void Add(IEnumerable<decimal> values, int index)
    {
        SetColumn(IEnumerable<decimal> values, int index);
    }

    protected IEnumerable<decimal> GetColumn(int index) { ... }

    protected void SetColumn(IEnumerable<decimal> values, int index) { ... }
}
```

then it can be used like :

```
var test = new Triangle(); 
var column = new List<decimal> { 4.7m, 68.36m, 889.14m };

test[0] = column;
// or 
test.Add(column);
```

For the placement of the methods. If you see there is a method is off the class functionality (like CalculateReserves()), you can move it to another class that is linked to the current one (for instance, you can create a calculation class, as an extension class  that would have all the calculations methods, and you can sort them out. (for instance, `test.Calculate().Cashflows().Sum()`). this API would be applied on all Triangle, Square, ..etc. So, yes it's possible and also doable.

> So, is it sensible to store the calculated values inside a private
>   class array instead of recalculating it?

Yes, and it's also possible to have a private property where it holds the total sum of the added values, so in your `Add()` method, you can add every new value in the private property `_total += value;` and retrieve it where you need it. This method would speed things up for the calculations part. If you have mutliple totals (say cashflow, expenses, ..etc. to sum, you might store them in a List or Array or A Dictionary. If these are few sums (say you have only 5 different types of sums to store) then use 5 variables (one for each) to avoid using extra collections.

just use your good judgement on your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. I applied your suggestions considering the namespaces (Methods was meant to be something like ReservingMethods, so I changed it to that, I moved the Exceptions to the namespace they apply to) re-added the interfaces and implemented the Calculations-extension class. I does make more sense to move it to the ReservingMethods namespace, thank you. However, although I really liked your approach of letting Triangle implement IEnumerable, I couldn't think of a sensible implementation for the Remove-method considering the domain. I keep that in mind though.

Comment: @jb262 for the Remove method it's just a habit where I always provide the basic functions (add, edit, remove, search). You can remove whatever functionality that don't fit under your business requirement. However, considering this would be used by other developers as well, I would leave it for them as they might need it in their implementations.